# How to link specific item info to template from list of items in emberjs

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I am learning emberjs and I'm stuck on trying to display a specific lien from a list of liens on a template. Im successfully reaching the template but unable to display the lien's info on the table:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gaqavu/2/edit?html,js,output

Im mostly confused with the use of controllers, which I'm sure I need to use for this to work.

These are the controllers I have right now:

```
App.LienController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    addToPortfolio: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('isInPortfolio');
    }
  }
});

App.LiensController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController:'lien'
});
```

These are the liens:

```
App.LIENS=[
  {
          id: 1,
          apn: 'apn1',
          fips: '01700',
          state: 'CA',
          county: 'Los Angeles',
          address: 'somewhere st123',
          debt: 4000,
          isBiddedOn: false, //check later
          isInPortfolio: false
  },
  {
          id: 2,
          apn: 'apn2',
          fips: '01744',
          state: 'FL',
          county: 'Miami',
          address: 'someplace st700',
          debt: 2000,
          isBiddedOn: false, //check later
          isInPortfolio: false        
  },
  {
          id: 3,
          apn: 'apn3',
          fips: '05690',
          state: 'FL',
          county: 'Orlando',
          address: 'ExactPlace in st111',
          debt: 2500,
          isBiddedOn: false, //check later
          isInPortfolio: false
  }
];
```

This is what I am doing in the html on the lien template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="lien">
    <h2 class="sub-header" >Lien</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>apn</th>
              <th>fips code</th>
              <th>State</th>
              <th>County</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Debt</th>
              <th>Current Bid</th>
            </tr>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>{{lien.id}}</td>
              <td>{{apn}}</td>
              <td>{{fips}}</td>
              <td>{{state}}</td>
              <td>{{county}}</td>
              <td>{{address}}</td>
              <td>${{debt}}</td>
            </tr>
  </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `model` hook inside your `LienRoute` does a `findBy` using `params.id`

```
App.LienRoute= Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return App.LIENS.findBy('id', params.id);
  }
});
```

`params.id` is a string, but you have `id` defined in your model as an integer. For this to work, you need to convert the string to an integer as follows:

```
App.LienRoute= Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return App.LIENS.findBy('id', parseInt(params.id));
  }
});
```

Also, when you are linking to a lien, you need to use

```
{{#link-to 'lien' lien tagName='td'}}{{lien.id}}{{/link-to}}
```

passing in a variable `lien` as opposed to

```
{{#link-to 'lien' this tagName='td'}}{{lien.id}}{{/link-to}}
```

since each time through the loop, your context is inside that model variable

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dufuqe/3/edit?html,js)

Comment: What I would like to achieve is clicking a lien in the portfolio and show the lien template with the info of that specific lien that was clicked

Comment: You are looping through liens with each var being a `lien`, so it should be `{{#link-to 'lien' lien tagName='td'}}{{lien.id}}{{/link-to}}`

Comment: You my friend are a fkn BOSS! Thanks a ton! Add that part to the answer so I can mark it as accepted.